# Ошибка Invalid Reverse Solidus '\' declaration при разборе json

Tags: c#, json

Прошу помощи в разборе JSON.

Пытаюсь распарсить Yandex коллекции с обновляемой лентой, вот сам сайт:
https://yandex.ru/collections/avto/

При анализе XHR удалось определить, что при листинге отправляются Get запросы, вот пример запроса:

https://yandex.ru/collections/api/user/feed?type=auto_and_moto&card_id.after=5a512d7f215a8400a1d672d0&seed=1563859591660-721538998082063&after=24&rec_flags=user_interface%3Ddesktop%3Bpreset%3Dcollections%3Bfrom%3Dcollections

Если пройти по ссылке то сгенерится JSON (по крайней мере на него похож). Собственно прошу помощи в его парсинге для возможности десериализации. 
Думал воспользоваться генератором классов http://json2csharp.com, но он его не скушал...

Поделитесь методикой разбора таких конструкций? Желательно на C#.

Comment: пробуйте через библиотекой Newtonsoft.Json, у него есть возможность десериализации JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ВАШ_КОЛЛЕКЦИЯ>(ВАШ_JSON); где ВАШ_КОЛЛЕКЦИЯ - это класс-сопоставление к структуре json данным

Comment: особо не вижу проблем, там есть previous, next и основная коллекция results

Comment: Я обычно так и делаю. Проблема как раз в получении структуры json. Если вы посмотрите пример, поймете, что он очень сложен для разбора. Руки чешутся сделать регулярками, но это зашквар...

Comment: А есть ли способ приводить для разбора такие конструкции в более читабельный вид, чтобы не ломать глаза?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Посмотрел в браузере ваш json вручную:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вставить текст в vscode и нажать alt+shift+F - текст прекрасно форматируется, т.е. сам json валидный.

Дело и не в размере json - я попробовал проверить гипотезу "на сайте который вы привели большие файлы не анализируются, допустим стоит ограничение на длину POST запроса" и открыл в своём любимом анализаторе, делюсь ссылкой: https://app.quicktype.io/ -- и он совершенно спокойно открыл его.

Но! Выдал ошибку, которую я никогда не видел (спасибо за любопытный кейс, с которым не сталкивался):

> Invalid Reverse Solidus '\' declaration.

Я погуглил, похоже это какая-то проблема ([1](https://github.com/codenothing/jsonlint/issues/2), [2](https://github.com/quicktype/quicktype/issues/1243)) у конкретного семейства парсеров - им не нравится unicode.

Окей, открываем любой редактор который поддерживает замену регекспами и заменяем `\\u[\da-zA-Z]{4}` на скажем букву Z.

Вуяля! Такой текст прекрасно анализируется -- выдаёт классы для десериализации.

Comment: Супер. Спасибо! Вручную каждый раз лепить такую структуру - застрелишься.

Comment: Держи баг: `{"field":"\\u0000000000"}`

Comment: @Qwertiy ух ты, это откуда такое? по стандарту возможно?

Comment: @AK, конечно. Экранирую обратный слеш ```\\```, а потом идёт любой текст.

Comment: Чем ответ из первого комментария не угодил?

Comment: Кстати, скорее всего тоже баг: `{"field":"\u000A"}`.

Comment: @Qwertiy Первый комментарий о том, что можно взять Json.Net и конвертировать им. Если у тебя есть классы. Так вот вопрос был не о том, что ошибка в json.net - а в том, что этих классов нет, руками писать долго, а типовые тулзы не умеют распознавать. Если бы Json.Net умел бы по строке сгенерировать классы - то первый коммент подошёл бы в качестве ответа, но эта библиотека не предназначена для этого.

Comment: @AK, он вроде может в словари конвертировать вообще без классов.